# Gradle run instrumentation test - how to exclude a package using command line?

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, android-instrumentation

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint documentation tells you how to include a class while test run. Example

`./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.android.testing.blueprint.ui.espresso.EspressoTest`

Is there a command which can be used for gradle instrumentation test run to exclude a package using command line?

Answer (score 1):

I used -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.notPackage=com.example.foo option in gradle test run command. It works!

Source:
https://medium.com/stepstone-tech/exploring-androidjunitrunner-filtering-options-df26d30b4f60